# How is Bigquery Async Job is different from Batch Query?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I got stuck in choosing between Job vs Job Class in defining a job function in my application and how is batch query is different  from Job class ? 
 https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/reference.html#job

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear to me what it is you're asking, but I'll take a shot at it.

All `jobs` in BigQuery are async. This means when you submit your job to BigQuery (query, copy, load or extract) the job begins execution on the BigQuery service and returns immediately with a job id. You can then use that job id to poll for the status of the job e.g. `running`, `failed`, `done` etc.

The `JobConfig` object is what you pass to the `Job` when you want to run a job. This object encapsulates all the details of your job e.g. it might contain the SQL to run when using a QueryJob etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response but if you refer the link they provided `Job Class` also which needs bigquery client as a parameter and in the document it specifically says Asynchronous which create confusion to me as I can do the same thing with BATCH query by setting the `priority` parameter in the `job.QueryJobConfig` and pass the config to the `query` method of the `Client`.

So my question is what's the use of Job Class and how it is different from BATCH query

Comment: The "Job Class" is the actual async job. There are two types of queries: Interactive and Batch. The difference is explained here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries